# When I make a shared library, a error occur

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I made a shared library as the follow:

1. `gcc -c output.c`
2. `gcc -shared -fPIC -o liboutput.so output.o`

When output.c is the follow, it could work.

```
//#include "output.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int output(const char* st) {
    return 1+2;
}
```

But, when output.c changed as the follow, a error occur.

```
//#include "output.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int output(const char* st) {
    printf("%s\n", st);
    return 1+2;
}
```

This is error message:

> /usr/bin/ld: output.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined 符号 `puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld: 最后的链结失败: 错误的值
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I want to know why and how to deal it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile `output.c` as position independent code.

`gcc -c -fPIC output.c`

In the first version you have not called any library function. But in second one `printf` is being called. In general, compile all sources with `-fPIC` if you intend to build a shared library later.